# XML transformation using XSLT logic

Tags: xml, xslt

Suppose I have an XML with structure (a snippet from a large XML):

```
<refbody>
<question>test</question>
<answer>test</answer>
</refbody>
```

The XSLT should put the `question` and `answer` in separate `<p>` tags. For that, I'm using the XSLT below.

Is there a more elegant approach rather than writing two `xsl:template`s? Can it be done using one `xsl:template` and `xsl:if`? It didn't work when I tried.

XSLT:

```
<xsl:template match="question">
    <p>
    <b><xsl:apply-templates/></b>
    </p>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="refbody | answer">
      <p>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </p>
</xsl:template>
```

produces the output:

```
<p class='refbody'>
<p class='question'><b>test</b></p>
<p class='answer'>test</p>
</p>
```

Combining the above in one `xsl:template` doesn't work:

```
<xsl:template match="refbody | answer | question">
<xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="question">
    <p><b><xsl:apply-templates/></b></p>
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:when test="refbody|answer">
    <p><xsl:apply-templates/></p>
  </xsl:when>
</xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: What is the target format, is that HTML? I don't think you can nest `p` elements in HTML. As for the XSLT, what is the result you want?

Comment: I chose that as an example. I'm actually converting it to DITA. I want the result as the output I get when I run the 1st XSLT: `<p>
<p><b>test</b>
<p>test</p>
</p>`. I'll change it to valid HTML.

Comment: Both in your post as well as in the comment that snippet has three `<p>` start tags but only two `</p>` end tags so it is not even clear which structure you want to create.

Comment: What do you understand by "more elegant approach"? What is the problem with two `xsl:template`s? Personally I think that your current approach is elegant enough.

Comment: @MartinHonnen edited. hope it's clear now. Wasn't formatted properly. My apologies.

Comment: @friedemann_bach for a large XML, I'm having to add multiple templates like this. So wanted to do it without using so many templates.

Comment: Yes, makes sense!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from any consideration what is more or less elegant, the solution you are looking for is probably something like this:

```
<xsl:template match="refbody | answer | question">
    <p>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="self::question">
            <b><xsl:apply-templates/></b>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
    </p>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Was missing that self:: reference. How is it different than just writing `question`? Also, is there a way to check if the `b` tag already exists before applying it?

Comment: `self::question` looks "in the mirror", while `question` looks for children. This indirectly answers your second question: If you want to check whether `b` already exists, then the when-statement should read `self::question and not(b)`.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Wasn't aware of the ::self part.

Answer (score 0):

If you think that using `xsl:choose` is somehow more elegant than using two template rules, I have to tell you that you are wrong. Experienced XSLT users will always choose separate template rules in preference. It gives you much better modularity: your code is more resilient to changes, either in the source document structure or in the rendering requirements.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Didn't know that.